# Middle name missing on Chinese visa in passport, could this be a problem?

Tags: visas, china, sri-lankan-citizens

My middle name is missing on the Chinese visa in my passport. Other details are correct. Could this be a problem?

I got the visa via a visa consultation company. I asked the consultation company about it but they said embassy wrote the name without a middle name because of lack of space to write the full name. They said that the Chinese visa system has the full name, but now I am scared this can be a problem for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't a problem. The china immigration officer didn't say anything about it. Actually immigration officer system had my full name as the passport. visa consultation company are correct with skip middle name because of less space.

but always double-check with the embassy if happed similar situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This could be an issue, as often they want the visa to match exactly to the name in the passport, but that being said it is also very common for names that are too long to have their middle name removed (in many countries including China), so they are used to this happening. It really comes down to who is checking your visa on the day, as no matter what the consulate says, the border officer will have the final say.

If you have time, try to get in contact with the consulate and ask for the visa to be altered to fit your name, if they insist that it is fine the way it is, get it in writing and print it off so you have proof to show if there is an issue.